# YCAD Library Usage

Tags: autocad, cad, sourceforge, dxf

I started using the [`YCAD Library`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ycad/). The problem is that I cannot find any usage instructions and I am kind of confused because I have no idea how to use it. I am hoping that somebody here used it before or is using it now so he/she can give me some tips how to use the library.

Thank you in advance.

PS.

One of the requirements for the project is to develop it in `Java`. I know that there are some good libraries in C#, C++, etc. but I need to do it in `Java`.

Best regards, Dimitar Georgiev

Comment: I have the same problem... I can't find any proper example to generate a DXF file especially for MTEXT. chikito1990 did you figure out to handle the library? I would appreciate every code snippet!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Import the classes such as `com.ysystems.ycad.lib.yxxf.Yxxf`.

Open the file object:

```
File flname = new File(filename);
```

Open the buffered input stream with the file:

```
BufferedInputStream is = null;
```

Open the buffered stream:

```
is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(flname ));
```

Create the `Yxxf` object:

```
Yxxf dxfDrawing = new Yxxf();
```

Create the `YdxfGetBuffer`:

```
YdxfGetBuffer buffStream = new YdxfGetBuffer();
```

Set the type:

```
int typ = YdxfGetBuffer.GET_TYPE_MAIN; 
buffStream .setInput(typ, in, drawing);
YdxfGet.get(buffStream );
```

After this, you may probably find the objects and iterate through.