# YCad DXF Library code example

Tags: java, file, io, dxf

I'm currently working on a java project and need to export a DXF with lines and text. Especially MTEXT which is a multi-line text in AutoCAD DXF files.

I was hoping that anyone here already used the "[Ycad](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ycad/)" Library. I can't find any code example and I only have the documentation which doesn't help me right away. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512202/ycad-library-usage/29879083#29879083) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801956/save-dxf-file-in-java) are the only examples I found...

I would need a code snipped which shows how to create a new DXF File, insert lines and text entities and write the file via the Ycad library.
I would be very thankful if anyone could give me a hint!

Thanks in advance